# Webpack: Добавить функционал к библиотеке в другом модуле (на примере jQuery + animate.css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

В данном примере функционал библиотеки jQuery расширен функционалом `animate.css` (пример базирован на [официальной документации](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/); язык - TypeScript, хотя за исключением объявления `interface JQuery` это чистый JavaScript):

**AnimateCssJQuery.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

interface JQuery {
  animateCss(): JQuery;
}

$.fn.extend({
  animateCss: function(animationName, callback) {
    let animationEnd = (function(el) {
      let animations = {
        animation: 'animationend',
        OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
        MozAnimation: 'mozAnimationEnd',
        WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
      };

      for (let t in animations) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
          return animations[t];
        }
      }
    })(document.createElement('div'));

    this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);

      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
    });

    return this;
  },
});
```

Если мы просто импортируем этот файл в другой (таким способом как `import './LibraryExtensions/animate.css/AnimateCssJQuery'`), то будет ошибка `Property 'animateCss does not exist on type 'JQuery <HTMLElement>`. Может я ошибаюсь, но вероятно это потому, что результат расширения библиотеки jQuery не был импортирован, но поскольку результат этого импорта не записан ни в какую переменную, то не совсем понятно, как это импортировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в папке с Вашим кодом создать файл `typings.d.ts` и сделать расширение интерфейса:

```
interface JQuery {
    animateCss: (animationName: string, callback: () => void) => JQuery;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, эффект отсутствует. Даже как-то грустно сообщать об этом после того, как Вы написали вежливый ответ с обращением на "Вы" с большой буквы :(

Comment: @БоковГлеб, исправил

Comment: всё заработало! Благодарю Вас за ответ! Не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему нужно делать это объявление интерфейса именно в **typings.d.ts**? По сути, это файл с глобальными настройками проекта, но в идеале хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы данное объявление интерфейса было частью расширения библиотеки, то есть было бы с ним если не в том же файле (**AnimateCssJQuery.ts**), то хотя бы одной папке.

Comment: `.d` значит `declaration` (объявление типа(ов), в ранних версиях TypeScript нужно было использовать так называемые `директивы с тройным слешем` (`/// <reference path="..." />`) и таким образом указывать в каждом файле, чтобы файл `.ts` знал об определенных типах, сейчас TypeScript на этапе компиляции рекурсивно делает `include` всех `.d.ts` файлов в директории с `tsconfig.json` (то есть где Ваш workspace), но можно такую возможность отключить и вручную указывать файлы в `tsconfig.json > include: ['./path-to/typings.d.ts']`

Comment: Понял. А как вообще поступают, когда какой-то новый тип добавляется определённой библиотекой? Каждый раз при добавлении этой библиотеки вручную прописывают новые типы в **tsconfig.json**? Или это как-то можно автоматизировать?

Comment: Сейчас все библиотеки предоставляют свои определения (`@types`), если уж на то пошло, то создавать файл `.d.ts` файл и в нем прописывать, называть его можете как угодно, `typings` это просто эдакой стандарт. Не нужно вручную ничего прописывать, я же сказал что компилятор рекурсивно делает `include` всех определений, а в `tsconfig` можно просто вручную указать путь (`glob`), где лежат Ваши определения, если Вы не хотите, чтобы компилятор видел все

Comment: Ну вот например, я хочу создать определение `interface JQuery { animateCss: (animationName: string, callback: () => void) => JQuery; }` для библиотеки `AnimateSass-JQuery`, но оно должно быть частью этой библиотеки, а не объявляться глобально на уровне проекта. В папку с библиотекой AnimateSass-JQuery вдобавок  к файлу с логикой `AnimateSass-JQuery.ts` я добавляю `AnimateSass-JQuery.d.ts` с Вашим определением `interface JQuery { ... }`. Что ещё надо сделать, чтобы при подключении этой библиотеки не было ошибки `Property animateCss does not exist on type JQuery <HTML Element>` ?

Comment: Либо Вы делаете частью проекта, либо контрибьютите в `@types/jquery` :-)

Comment: Попробовал разные решения. Решение с `/// <reference path="AnimateSass-JQuery.d.ts" />` хотя и устаревшие, но эмоционально наиболее приятное. То есть библиотека сама объявляет нужный интерфейс, который автоматически становится доступен при подключении библиотеки, и не нужно ничего прописывать при подключении библиотеки.

Comment: Устаревшее, но делайте, как Вам удобно

Comment: да разве только мне :) Разве тому, кто будет использовать библиотеку, не будет удобно? (не надо ничего прописывать в typings.d.ts при подключении)

Comment: Если Вы делаете свою библиотеку и хотите, чтобы другие устанавливали ее, как пакет, то сейчас стандарт это либо делать еще один пакет `@types/your-library`, либо в корне этой библиотеки создавать `.d.ts`. Вот Вам как пример https://github.com/prettymuchbryce/node-http-status

Comment: посмотрел пример. У меня в корне библиотеки .d.ts (а именно AnimateSass-JQuery.d.ts) уже есть, но через `export declare interface`, как в примере, typescript не находит нужные типы. Что-то я упустил...

Answer (score 0):

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.9.2",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.5"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

1. **A**

**index.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        qwa(): JQuery;
    }
    interface JQueryStatic {
        qwabra: string
    }
}

$().qwa //(method) JQuery<HTMLElement>.qwa(): JQuery<HTMLElement>
$.qwabra //(property) JQueryStatic.qwabra: string
```

2. **B**

**index.d.ts**

```
interface JQuery {
    qwa(): JQuery;
}
interface JQueryStatic {
    qwabra: string
}
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="index.d.ts" />

import * as $ from 'jquery'

$().qwa //(method) JQuery<HTMLElement>.qwa(): JQuery<HTMLElement>
$.qwabra //(property) JQueryStatic.qwabra: string
```

---

можно через `@types` вместо `/// <reference path="index.d.ts" />`